# Primefaces / JQuery : Components are inactive after ajax update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces for one of my projects everything is cool until today a weird problem occurred, if i use `<p:ajax update="id_component"/>` to update some primefaces component, the component lose it value and becomes inactive (unclickable).

After a long time testing i found out that any component that uses **JQuery** becomes inactive after an **Ajax request** witch just suddenly happened !.

**here is a code example :**

```
<div class="row" >
                                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                                <h:outputLabel value="Campagne : "/> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                                <h:selectOneMenu id="ycamp" value="#{homeSupGBean.idCamp1}">
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choisir " itemValue="0"/>
                                                    <f:selectItems value="#{homeSupGBean.campagnesInOrga}" var="camp" itemLabel="#{camp.name}" itemValue="#{camp.id}"/>
                                                    <p:ajax  update="year ycamp"/>                                                                                          
                                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                                <h:outputLabel value="Années : "/> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                                <p:selectOneMenu id="year" value="#{homeSupGBean.year}">
                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choisir " itemValue="0"/>
                                                    <f:selectItems var="year" value="#{homeSupGBean.years}" itemLabel="#{year}" itemValue="#{year}"/>
                                                    <p:ajax listener="#{homeSupGBean.getProgOfCampInYear()}" oncomplete="chartProgOfCampInYear()" update="values"/>
                                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Image [OnLoad] :
[image]

Image [After Ajax Update] :
[image]

**EDITED :**
I used F12 as suggested by @BalusC to see generated HTML code from primefaces component before and after ajax update.

**Before :**

```
<div id="formm:year" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <input aria-disabled="false" aria-describedby="formm:year_0" aria-activedescendant="formm:year_0" aria-owns="formm:year_items" aria-autocomplete="list" id="formm:year_focus" name="formm:year_focus" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="text"></div><div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <select id="formm:year_input" name="formm:year_input" tabindex="-1" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;formm:year&quot;,e:&quot;valueChange&quot;,p:&quot;formm:year&quot;,u:&quot;formm:values&quot;,onco:function(xhr,status,args){chartProgOfCampInYear();}});">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Choisir </option><option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label id="formm:year_label" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all">Choisir </label>
    <div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**After Ajax Upadate :**

```
<div id="formm:year" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <input id="formm:year_focus" name="formm:year_focus" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <select id="formm:year_input" name="formm:year_input" tabindex="-1" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;formm:year&quot;,e:&quot;valueChange&quot;,p:&quot;formm:year&quot;,u:&quot;formm:values&quot;,onco:function(xhr,status,args){chartProgOfCampInYear();}});">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Choisir </option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label id="formm:year_label" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all">&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="formm:year_panel" class="ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow">
        <div class="ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper" style="height:auto">
            <ul id="formm:year_items" class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset" role="listbox">
                <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Choisir " tabindex="-1" role="option">Choisir </li>
                <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="2016" tabindex="-1" role="option">2016</li>
                <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="2015" tabindex="-1" role="option">2015</li>
                <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="2014" tabindex="-1" role="option">2014</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS Console :** the error in the image appear when i load the page for the first time [Nothing change when ajax update is fired].
[image]

I hope you understand what is happening here because i don't, thank you for your time.

Comment: Please elaborate the problem as a developer not as an enduser. To start, do you see any clues in browser console? (press F12 in webbrowser to open the web developer toolset with the console)

Comment: Please check the update and i hope i provided more useful information and thank you .

Comment: So there are no errors in JS console?

Comment: So you've manually installed and included jQuery in your web application?

Comment: I don't see any error when i fire the ajax update look at the screen shot for details

Comment: The error on load is preventing jQuery from doing any further necessary work for which the enduser would first notice observable consequences. If you fix that error which occurs on load, then all consequences will automagically disappear. So, again, are you indeed manually including a copy of jquery.js file along with the webapp?

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't see any error ? can you please be more specific.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111849/discussion-between-simoi-chigo-and-balusc).

Comment: no i didn't manually includ a copy of jquery.js , primefaces load the jquery file on it's own, right ??
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/AppName/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.3"‌​></script>`

Comment: It was just a question to exclude a possible cause, because the root cause of your problem is not visible in the information provided so far. I suggest to try creating a MCVE.

Comment: tried the latest 6.0RC?

Comment: Tried PrimeFaces 6.2?